# How to determine if a straight line is in front or behind another?

Tags: python, algorithm, logic, binary-tree

My question is basically what the title says but I will try to explain better. I have a bunch of lines, that serve as walls in a game that I am developing. I'm trying to apply the binary space partitioning algorithm to store the lines that are in front or behind another line that is picked randomly from the rest.

My question is how, mathematically, can I determine if a line is in front or behind another in my algorithm. I saw some videos on youtube, and apparently I need "normals", but I don't know how to obtain that or why I need it.

Comment: It'll be easier for us to help you out if you post an example of what you're trying right now as well as what you want to achieve.

Comment: If the lines are walls the game is 2D? How can a line be behind another one in 2D?

Comment: Please clarify the `front` and `behind` line part. Also some reference to where you saw the `normals` would help understand what you want to achieve

Comment: I have a raycaster rendering from a 2d map, but I want to split this map from the lines and thus generate a BSP tree, where in each node I have to determine which lines are in front of or behind another line, I haven't implemented anything related yet to that binary tree because I still can't imagine what my algorithm would be like because I don't know how to determine if a line is behind or in front of another

Comment: Something like that https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Veronica_Teichrieb/publication/257571726/figure/fig1/AS:383469831114752@1468437740736/Binary-Space-Partitioning-tree-BSP.png

Comment: I believe it is better to understand if you imagine this line as a wall in a 3d world, and I have to determine what is behind and what is in front, this also serves to render only when the player is in front of the wall and not behind

Comment: Here is a video that shows how the algorithm that i'm trying to implement works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTRzfKh4Tg0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not really the best place to ask broad questions on how to get started on something like this. Try Googling for guides first. Once you have code, if it has a problem and you've already tried solving it (and searching for answers) yourself, you can come here and ask for help with it. Post the code when you do so.

Comment: Sorry for that, i'm searching for a response for that question at least 2 weeks and i cant find content on yt or google that solves my question, people only explain the BSP verbally, and every time i try to implement what they said i end up with that question about lines in front or behind another which not permit me to start coding the algorithm. I will try finding more content about or some code examples and later i return to ask more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find the implicit equation for the line you're interested in.

- > 3D: F(x,y,z) = Ax + By + Cz + D = 0
- > 2D: F(x,y) = Ax + By + C = 0

2. Pick any point you're interested in, plug it's coordinates into the Line equation.

- > if F(x_1,y_1) < 0, point (x_1,y_1) is above the plane
- > if F(x_1,y_1) > 0, point (x_1,y_1) is below the plane